# Schema in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema, ssms

By default the schema name is dbo.mytable
How to I change it to my user specific schema name?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of survey. I found the answer!

Comment: it is always good to share your solution with community and accept it so that anyone who faces similar issue could look at your answer in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter schema of database using following query:

```
   ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER yourNewSchema.abc;
```

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx